# R function for count number while deleting the duplicates

Tags: r, string, apply, lapply, sapply

I have a dataframe, in which here is a column that contains different colors. My purpose is to count how many different colors are in this column. Note: "Red, 1", "1 Red", "Red 2" are all Red, so all above count as only one color. however, "Dark Red" is a different color

```
Item               Color
Flower             Red 1
Flower             Yellow 1
Flower             Red, 1
Flower             Red 2
Flower             2 red
Flower             Green, 1
Flower             Dark Red 1
Flower             Green, 2
Flower             Black
Flower             White 1
Flower             1A, Green
```

Because in this column, the structures of the color names are not identical. Hence I am not able to just use sub() to delete everything after the first word and count the number.
I have tried to use sapply(apply()) or grep() for approximate matching, but the result is not that ideal. I also tried to distinct() to remain all the unique color name but it fails in dealing with strings like "Red, 1" and "Red, 2"
For me, the most difficult situation is the color follows a comma, such as "1A, Blue" or something else

I hope the result could be

```
Flower    Red
Flower    Yellow
Flower    Green
Flower    Dark Red
Flower    Black
Flower    White
```

Or, simpler

```
6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say the dataframe is called `df` then you can use:

`length(unique(toupper(gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", df$Color))))`

Explanation:

`gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", df$Color)` removes anything that is not a character.  So you are left with just the colors.

`toupper`capitalizes the remaining text, and unique removes duplicates.  `length` gives you the number of elements in the vector.  You will get `5`.

**Addition**:  To handle the case of "Red, 1A" you can remove everything after the ',' and then use the above solution.  For example:

`x <- gsub(",.*$", "", df$Color) ## removes a comma and anything that follows`

`length(unique(toupper(gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", x))))  ## removes all but letters`

**Alternative** to removing everything after a comma:  You could remove any alpha numeric such as "1A" or "A1" with:

`x <- gsub("[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z]*", "", df$Color)`

Comment: Thank you! But I probably forget that what if there is a color "Red, 1A" ? then that 'A'  will remain too, am I correct?

Comment: Added a solution for the case "Red, 1A".  If a color could follow a comma, however, then this won't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate

Comment: You are welcome.  Added an alternative to removing everything after a comma in case you have "1A, Red" somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for loops, `*apply` or other, an appropriate regex will do most of the job.

```
x <- tolower(gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", flowers$Color))
unique(x)
#[1] "red"    "yellow" "green"  "black"  "white" 

length(unique(x))
#[1] 5
```

**Data.**

```
flowers <- read.table(text = "
Item               Color
Flower             'Red 1'
Flower             'Yellow 1'
Flower             'Red, 1'
Flower             'Red 2'
Flower             '2 red'
Flower             'Green, 1'
Flower             'Green, 2'
Flower             'Black'
Flower             'White 1'
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will see if it helps!

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate this works, but I still have a little question. since I find out that here is one color called "Dark Blue", applying your code the result is accurate but there is no space between Dark and Blue, which is "darkblue". I am wondering if there is anyway to make it a bit more elegant, like "deep blue"? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
flowers %>% 
    summarise(len = n_distinct(Item,  tolower(str_remove(Color, "[^A-Za-z]+"))))
#  len
#1   5
```

#### data

```
  flowers <- structure(list(Item = c("Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower"), Color = c("Red 1", 
"Yellow 1", "Red, 1", "Red 2", "2 red", "Green, 1", "Green, 2", 
"Black", "White 1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Thanks, may I ask if your code is trying to delete everything that is not a character>

Comment: @Cooper Here, the `^` inside the square bracket is matching all characters except A-Za-z letters and it is removed with `str_remove`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `stringr` package and `colors()`.

```
library(readr)
library(stringr)

A <- read_table("Item               Color
Flower             Red 1
Flower             Yellow 1
Flower             Red, 1
Flower             Red 2
Flower             2 red
Flower             Green, 1
Flower             Green, 2
Flower             Black
Flower             White 1")

A$Color <- casefold(A$Color, upper = TRUE)
colors_considered <- casefold(colors(), upper = TRUE)

bb <- as.data.frame(A$Color)
BB <- apply(bb,1,function(x) str_extract(x,colors_considered))

CC <- BB[!is.na(BB)]

output <- data.frame(item = A$Item,color = CC) %>%
 unique()
```

Output:

```
> output
    item  color
1 Flower    RED
2 Flower YELLOW
6 Flower  GREEN
8 Flower  BLACK
9 Flower  WHITE
```